About exercise of group representation
Let $G$ be symmetric group $S_3$, $V = \mathbb{C}^3$.
We define $\rho_s(x) = (x_{s^{-1}(1)},x_{s^{-1}(2)},x_{s^{-1}(3)})$ where $s \in G, x = (x_1,x_2,x_3)$
Then the map $s \mapsto \rho_s$ gives a representation of a group $G$ on $V$($\rho : G \rightarrow $GL($V$)).
I want to prove $\rho_{st} = \rho_s \circ \rho_t$. 
$\rho_{st}(x) = (x_{(st)^{-1}(1)},x_{(st)^{-1}(2)},x_{(st)^{-1}(3)}) = (x_{t^{-1}(s^{-1}(1))},x_{t^{-1}(s^{-1}(2))},x_{t^{-1}(s^{-1}(3))}) = \rho_t(x_{s^{-1}(1)},x_{s^{-1}(2)},x_{s^{-1}(3)}) = \rho_t \circ \rho_s(x) \neq \rho_s \circ \rho_t(x),$ for any $s,t \in G, x \in V$
Where did I go wrong.
